# How to unescape special characters in Javascript which have already been escaped by StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml()?

Tags: javascript, hibernate, spring

I'm working with Spring and Hibernate. I'm using [commons-lang.jar](http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi) to escape and unescape some special characters using the `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml()` and `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml()` of the class [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) respectively. It's working exactly I want. There is no problem at all.

Now, I want to unescape the same characters which have already been escaped by the `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml()` method in **JavaScript** (*not by using Java code at all*). I tried `escape()` and `unescape()` JavaScript functions in turn but obviously these functions work differently than those mentioned in the `StringEscapeUtils` class.

Is there a way in **JavaScript** to unescape those characters which have already been escaped by `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var elem = document.createElement("div");
elem.innerHTML = "&lt;&quot;&#39;"
elem.innerText || elem.textContent; //<"'
```

Comment: Hi.. I have the similar case. But some part of string is escaped and some are not. How to handle this?
Example :
       <select  id="selCountry" >
         <option value="notset">Please select</option>
          &lt;option value="US" title="United States"&gt;United States &lt;/option&gt;
     </select>

The values are part of response so it is escaped. whereas remaining parts are not escaped.

Comment: @javaG you should fix whatever is escaping the country values

Comment: u mean.. to unescape the response(country values)?

Comment: @javaG no I mean not escaping them in the first place